# Display characters matched in strings

Tags: java

Very new to learning java and I'm working on a simple program that displays the number of matched characters between two user inputted strings. At the end it will display the total number of characters that matched as well as the letters that matched. I'm stuck on how to carry the value out of the inner for loop back to the main method to be called.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CountMatches
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int matches = 0;
        String aString;
        String anotherString;


        Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a String >> ");
        aString = inputDevice.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter another string>> ");
        anotherString = inputDevice.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < aString.length(); ++i)
        {

            for(int j = 0; j < anotherString.length(); ++j)
            {
                if(aString.charAt(i) == anotherString.charAt(j))
                    matches++;

            }

        }

       System.out.println(matches + " character(s) in " + aString + " are 
       also in " + anotherString);

   }
}
```

Edit: I should also mention that this assignment I'm working on, I haven't gotten to the point where I'm utilizing arrays. We have just covered loops and if then statements. So I am very early on in studying java.

Comment: " I'm stuck on how to carry the value out of the inner for loop back to the main method to be called." Can you elaborate more? I see you are already able to print the number of matched characters  in your main method using println? What else are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you provide a small example? Give a small input and the desired output, will then be far more easy to understand what you want to achieve. Also what is the current output of your program?

Comment: I also want to display which characters were matched. 

For example if aString = table and anotherString = fable

I want another println to say "The characters in table that are also in fable are: a b l e

Comment: The current output of my program displays the number of characters that match between aString and anotherString. But I also want to display which characters matched between those two strings.

Answer (score 1):

An easist, best and less code, example:

```
Set<Character> aStringSet = new TreeSet<Character>();
for(int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++) {
    aStringSet.add(aString.charAt(i));
}

Set<Character> anotherSet = new TreeSet<Character>();
for(int i = 0; i < anotherString.length(); i++) {
    anotherSet.add(anotherString.charAt(i));
}

aStringSet.retainAll(anotherSet);
System.out.print(aStringSet.size() + " character(s) in " + aString + " are also in " + anotherString);
System.out.println(" matched characters are " + aStringSet.toString());
```

Output:

```
Enter a String >> table
Enter another string>> fable
4 character(s) in table are also in fable matched characters are [a, b, e, l]
```

I have used [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). And [`retainAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-)  in `TreeSet` to get matched elements.

> Oracle Doc:
>
> ```
> retainAll(Collection<?> c)
> ```
>
> Retains only the elements in this set that are contained in the
>   specified collection (optional operation).

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not correct. Might want to explore some other data structures like Stack and ArrayList while you are at it. Will look something like this.

```
    int matches = 0;
    String aString;
    String anotherString;


    Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a String >> ");
    aString = inputDevice.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter another string>> ");
    anotherString = inputDevice.nextLine();

    System.out.println(aString);
    System.out.println(anotherString);

    // we will store astring characters in a stack data structure
    Stack<Character> aStringStack = new Stack<Character>();
    // a list to store the matched characters
    List<Character> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

    //First adding all the chars from astring to the Stack
    for(int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++)
    {
        aStringStack.push(aString.charAt(i));
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < aStringStack.size(); i++)
    {
        //Now iterating over the astring stack and popping the 
        // values from the top one at a time
        char temp = aStringStack.pop();

        for(int j = 0; j < anotherString.length(); j++)
        {
            //If the popped value is present in the anotherstring
            // then incrementing the match counter and storing the
            //matched character in our matched character array list
            if(temp == anotherString.charAt(j))
            {
                matches++;
                tempList.add(temp);

                // Also important to break the loop here to avoid
                // getting duplicates
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    System.out.println(matches + " character(s) in " + aString + " are  also in " + anotherString);
    System.out.println(tempList);
```

Will also suggest to compare this answer with @Serge's answer to see how different data structures can be used to solve same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide some kind of a database for you characters and their counters. There are multiple ways to do it. The following uses the `HashMap` to do so, where your characters are keys, and counters are values. This is not a very efficient way, but it server the purpose of explanation.

```
    // allocate the char/counter map
    HashMap<Character, Integer> cMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < aString.length(); ++i) {

        for (int j = 0; j < anotherString.length(); ++j) {
            if (aString.charAt(i) == anotherString.charAt(j)) {
                // see if the char already has an associated counter
                Integer count = cMap.get(aString.charAt(i));
                if (count == null)
                    count = 0; // if no counter is found, create one and set it to '0' (before incrementing)
                count++; 

                cMap.put(aString.charAt(i), count); // put the new counter value in the map
                matches++;
            }
        }
    }

    // traverse all map entries and print the key/value (char/counter) paires
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : cMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to store the matching characters is to use a data structure. When you encounter a matching character in both Strings, you can add the character to a collection. Collections are data structures used to hold objects, in this instance; Characters. There's lots of different types of data structures, but the main types are Set, List, and Queue.

I've written a solution for you using an ArrayList:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountMatches {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String aString;
        String anotherString;
        List<Character> matchingChars = new ArrayList<Character>();

        Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a String >> ");
        aString = inputDevice.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        System.out.print("Enter another string>> ");
        anotherString = inputDevice.nextLine().toLowerCase();

        for (int i = 0; i < aString.length(); ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < anotherString.length(); ++j) {
                if (aString.charAt(i) == anotherString.charAt(j) && !matchingChars.contains(aString.charAt(i))) {
                    matchingChars.add(aString.charAt(i));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(matchingChars.size() + " character(s) in " + aString + " are also in " + anotherString);
        System.out.println("The Matching character(s) are " + matchingChars);
    }
}
```

We can print the contents of the list easily as it has it's own toString() method which returns a String containing all the matching chars!

```
Enter a String >> Hello
Enter another string>> chelo
4 character(s) in hello are also in chelo
The Matching character(s) are [h, e, l, o]
```

Because we're adding the characters to a list, which you can check the size of, you no longer need to keep count with the "matches" variable reference, because we can just call matchingChars.size().

In order to us prevent the same char being added to the list twice we must only add it to the list if the list does not contain it already, using [list.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-).

Also, as a  suggestion, (as I have in the example above) you could use the String.toLowercase() method to convert the strings to lowercase, so that the case of the characters is ignored when you are comparing the characters.

The [Java tutorial for Collections] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) may be worth a look if you would like to learn more about collections.

Comment: I don't know if this helps or changes what you have provided.

"Write an application that allows a user to enter two Strings. Output the number of characters in the first String that also appear in the second String, and output those characters."

Comment: Not really, but I've updated my answer to remove the duplicate characters for you if the character from the first word is is in the second word twice. I've tried to keep the code the same structure as your original code so that you can keep the majority of code you have already written.

Comment: I figured it working within the confines of my knowledge and what is expected of me at this point in my class. 

I added a new main method variable called String foundStr = " ";

this foundStr is used in the inner for loop that concatenates each found duplicate character and stores it to display in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Without using arrays or anything else the inner for loop looks like the following:

```
for(int j = 0; j < anotherString.length(); ++j)
        {
            if(aString.charAt(i) == anotherString.charAt(j))
            {
            matches++;
            aChar = aString.charAt(i);              
            foundStr = foundStr + " " + aChar;
            }

        }
```

foundStr is then used int he Main Method to display all matched characters between aString and anotherString.